# How does GebSpec hide the field _browser and what is $spock_sharedField__browser good for?

Tags: groovy, spock, geb, internals

I try to understand more about how Geb and Spock work internally to understand what is really happening in my tests.

I found that GebSpec which I extend to write my tests has a field `Browser _browser`.

I also found that GebSpec has a method `getBrowser()` which returns `_browser`, so `_browser` can be accessed over `getBrowser()` and `get_browser()`. But the interesting part is that while debugging in intelliJ expanding an instance of GebSpec shows no field `_browser` but only a field `$spock_sharedField__browser`.

A little example:

[Debugging my Class: The instance of GebSpec has a field spock_sharedField__browser but no field _browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ81p.png)

How do they manage to hide the `_browser` field from me in the debugger and why do they do it?

Recall a field Browser `_browser` is declared in GebSpec and a field `$spock_sharedField__browser` is not.

There also is no method `get$spock_sharedField__browser()` but I still can access and manipulate `$spock_sharedField__browser`.

I tried to do it myself:

[I wrote a class TestClass that declares `_browser` exactly analog to GebSpec, but if I debug here the field `_browser` is shown normally as one would expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B51y.png)

Can someone explain me what is going on?

Why hide `_browser`?

What is `$spock_sharedField__browser` good for?

UPDATE: I think the following code describes summarizes it pretty good:

```java
import geb.spock.GebSpec
class GebHomeSpec extends GebSpec{
    def "test Geb homepage"(){
        when:
        ['get$spock_sharedField__browser', 'getBrowser', 'get_browser'].each {
            try {
                println this."${it}"()
            } catch (MissingFieldException e) {
                println e
            }
        }
        ['$spock_sharedField__browser', 'browser', '_browser'].each {
            try {
                println this.getMetaClass().getAttribute(this, it)
            } catch (MissingFieldException e){
                println e
            }
        }

        then:
        true
    }
}
```

The result on the console is:

```java
null
geb.Browser@352ff4da
geb.Browser@352ff4da
null
groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: browser for class: GebHomeSpec
groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: _browser for class: GebHomeSpec
```

My interpretation, considering the answer of kriegaex, is that in the Compilation during the Spock transformation the field $spock_sharedField__browser is declared and the field _browser is removed. The field browser never existed. But there are still getters for browser and _browser. I wonder where there get their data from (in this case  geb.Browser@352ff4da) as none of the field exists anymore as the exceptions show. At least it matches with the debugging information (c.f. first picture/link) that shows the field $spock_sharedField__browser but neither a field _browser nor a field browser.

Finally I noticed (and I dont really know how to explain that) the getters for _browser and browser are outside of the class no longer available (see below). I thought the concept of private is not implemented in groovy and making getters private makes no sense to me anyways.

```java
import geb.spock.GebSpec
class Main {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GebSpec gebSpec = new GebSpec()
        ['get$spock_sharedField__browser', 'getBrowser', 'get_browser'].each {
            try {
                println gebSpec."${it}"()
            } catch (MissingFieldException e) {
                println e
            }
        }
        ['$spock_sharedField__browser', 'browser', '_browser'].each {
            try {
                println gebSpec.getMetaClass().getAttribute(gebSpec, it)
            } catch (MissingFieldException e){
                println e
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This leads to

```java
null
groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: $spock_sharedField__browser for class: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: $spock_sharedField__browser for class: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
null
groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: browser for class: geb.spock.GebSpec
groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: _browser for class: geb.spock.GebSpec
```

All in all I find this rather confusing and I wonder what this is good for. Why introduce $spock_sharedField__browser and remove _browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you use IntelliJ IDEA, you can just decompile the `GebSpec` class and will see something like this (this is what the Groovy compiler really produced when it compiled the library class):

```groovy
public class GebSpec extends Specification implements GroovyObject {
  // ...

  @Shared
  @FieldMetadata(
    line = 29,
    name = "_browser",
    ordinal = 2
  )
  protected volatile Browser $spock_sharedField__browser;

  // ...

  public Browser createBrowser() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    return !__$stMC && !BytecodeInterface8.disabledStandardMetaClass() ? (Browser)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[8].callConstructor(Browser.class, this.createConf()), Browser.class) : (Browser)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[6].callConstructor(Browser.class, var1[7].callCurrent(this)), Browser.class);
  }

  public Browser getBrowser() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    if (BytecodeInterface8.isOrigZ() && !__$stMC && !BytecodeInterface8.disabledStandardMetaClass()) {
      if (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(var1[11].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), (Object)null)) {
        Browser var3 = this.createBrowser();
        ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(var3, GebSpec.class, this, (String)"_browser");
      }
    } else if (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(var1[9].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), (Object)null)) {
      Object var2 = var1[10].callCurrent(this);
      ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty((Browser)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var2, Browser.class), GebSpec.class, this, (String)"_browser");
    }

    return (Browser)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[12].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), Browser.class);
  }

  // ...

  public Browser get$spock_sharedField__browser() {
    return this.$spock_sharedField__browser;
  }

  public void set$spock_sharedField__browser(Browser var1) {
    this.$spock_sharedField__browser = var1;
  }
}
```

I think you have dived deep enough already to understand without further explanation.

---

**Update:** I forgot to mention: Your test class does not inherit `GebSpec` (which again inherits from `Specification`, i.e. the code will not be transformed by Spock/Geb because it has the wrong base class. If you do this, though:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import geb.spock.GebSpec
import spock.lang.Shared

class FooIT extends GebSpec {
  @Shared
  def myField

  def test() {
    expect:
    true
  }
}
```

Then the decompiled code will be:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import geb.spock.GebSpec;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;
import org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorCollector;
import org.spockframework.runtime.SpockRuntime;
import org.spockframework.runtime.ValueRecorder;
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind;
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockMetadata;
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureMetadata;
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.FieldMetadata;
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.SpecMetadata;
import spock.lang.Shared;

@SpecMetadata(
  filename = "FooIT.groovy",
  line = 6
)
public class FooIT extends GebSpec {
  @Shared
  @FieldMetadata(
    line = 7,
    name = "myField",
    ordinal = 0
  )
  protected volatile Object $spock_sharedField_myField;

  public FooIT() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
  }

  @FeatureMetadata(
    line = 10,
    name = "test",
    ordinal = 0,
    blocks = {@BlockMetadata(
  kind = BlockKind.EXPECT,
  texts = {}
)},
    parameterNames = {}
  )
  public void $spock_feature_1_0() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    ErrorCollector $spock_errorCollector = (ErrorCollector)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[2].callConstructor(ErrorCollector.class, false), ErrorCollector.class);
    ValueRecorder $spock_valueRecorder = (ValueRecorder)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[3].callConstructor(ValueRecorder.class), ValueRecorder.class);

    Object var10000;
    try {
      try {
        SpockRuntime.verifyCondition($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder.reset(), "true", Integer.valueOf(12), Integer.valueOf(5), (Object)null, $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(Integer.valueOf(0)), true));
        var10000 = null;
      } catch (Throwable var13) {
        SpockRuntime.conditionFailedWithException($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder, "true", Integer.valueOf(12), Integer.valueOf(5), (Object)null, var13);
        var10000 = null;
      } finally {
        ;
      }

      var1[4].call(var1[5].call(this.getSpecificationContext()));
    } finally {
      $spock_errorCollector.validateCollectedErrors();
      var10000 = null;
    }

  }

  public Object get$spock_sharedField_myField() {
    return this.$spock_sharedField_myField;
  }

  public void set$spock_sharedField_myField(Object var1) {
    this.$spock_sharedField_myField = var1;
  }
}
```

---

**Update 2:**

As for your additional questions, I can only speculate about the answers, I am sure users like *@erdi* (Geb maintainer), *@Szymon Stepniak*, *@Leonard Brünings* (who seem to be Groovy cracks, which I am not) could say more about it, but OTOH this is not a discussion forum and the questions are not particularly well suited for SO. Anyway, I edited the question tags to include "groovy" so as to maybe raise their attention.

> Why introduce `$spock_sharedField__browser` and remove `_browser`?

I think it is just the result of Spock's way of transforming the `@Shared` annotation into a member variable with named so as to very unlikely collide with any existing member names. You also see this happening in the decompiled version of my own Spock/Geb specification.

> But there are still getters for `browser` and `_browser`.

Of course there is a getter for `browser`, as in the Geb DLS you usually don't look behind the scenes but just use the syntactic sugar `browser` to access the browser instance. This Groovy-ism will call `getBrowser()`, as you probably know. This particular getter is declared explicitly in the `GebSpec` class in order to make the member conveniently accessible (you also see some lazy browser instantiation logic here):

```groovy
Browser getBrowser() {
    if (_browser == null) {
        _browser = createBrowser()
    }
    _browser
}
```

> I wonder where there get their data from (in this case geb.Browser@352ff4da) as none of the field exists anymore as the exceptions show.

I do not know enough about Groovy's dynamic language features to answer that, but you can see the actual mechanics in my decompiled code snippets.

Accessing Spock-specific class members from outside a running specification obviously does not work and probably is not meant to be. But if you run this test, it works just fine:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import geb.spock.GebSpec
import spock.lang.Shared

class FooIT extends GebSpec {
  @Shared
  def myField = "foo"

  def test() {
    given:
    println browser
    println myField
    expect:
    true
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
geb.Browser@1722011b
foo
```

Comment: I would love to hear further explanations :D

Comment: I am new to this so correct when I'm wrong. Somewhere in the compilation happens a Spock Transformation (http://dkublik.github.io/the-magic-behind-the-spock/) that effectively changes my source code. It declares a field $spock_sharedField__browser that didn't exist before. But now the field _browser no longer exists. That corresponds with what my debugger shows but now I wonder from where getBrowser() gets its data as _browser no longer exists. Note that getBrowser() and get$spock_sharedField__browser() don't return the same. Did _browser just vanish or does it still just exist somewhere?